# ntfs header files recovery

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

I have an external harddisk attached to an airport wireless router and somewhat after a few read and writes it is corrupted

I tried to attach that to my mac and I can't fix it. It looks like the header of the fs is corrupted. What is a good way to recover/fix that?

Any tools on Windows/Mac/Linux would do.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of R-Studio. More than once it's managed to recover from disasters other tools failed on.

Answer (score 0):

RecoverMyFiles has worked for me in a number of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Zero Assumption Recovery. It was even able to re-build and recover data from a RAID-0 array after the controller died.